# Can not resolve reference: `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract in Android App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I developed a Xamarin Cross Platform application that is working perfectly on Windows but when I try to recompile for Android I get the following error:

*Can not resolve reference: `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract*

I use the Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract reference because of the Windows.Storage class (generate files in internal memory).
I understand that I may have to change the recording method on Android but I can't even get to that stage...
How do I resolve this situation?

Comment: `Windows` namespace relies on features that exist only in Windows. Can't use that on other platforms. Move that code to `Windows` folder of your app, or put `#if Windows` around it, and around the `using Windows..`  to hide it from other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as ToolmakerSteve said, `Windows namespace relies on features that exist only in Windows.` The reference should not be in the main .Net Standard library but in the UWP Application.

First, you can move the code to the Windows folder or set the `#if Windows` around it.

Second, you can write the code for each platform. I found the answer you can refer to [Can not resolve reference: `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127726/can-not-resolve-reference-windows-foundation-universalapicontract-in-android).